# Kotlin donot refresh previous activity on intenting new activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Could you please help me with the below scenario ?

Amount - Edit text field
Category - text field
notes - Edit text field

In the above fields when i click category it will go to new activity and select the category. But after selecting amount value and notes values got reset.

Suggest me some good idea when i choose category the entered value on amount and notes remains same.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Share your code, how you are doing this

Comment: I couldnt share because of terms and condition